# Android audio mixer ZeroOneZeroR

Tags: android, audio, directory, path, mixer

I am a student, an aspiring indie developer on android. For my application, I want to use library to mix audio sounds. "https://github.com/ZeroOneZeroR/android_audio_mixer"
But I'm confused.. If my project has the necessary mp3 files in the resources in the "raw" folder (see the screenshot 1), how can I submit them to the "input1Path" variable (see the screenshot 2)? I have an error..
I will be very grateful if you help me!
With respect

screenshot 1[image]
screenshot 2[image]

I want to mix sounds using this library from the "raw" folder in mp3 format and receive the final audio file in the same folder (if possible).